# Annotating function with TypeVar and default value results in union type

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

When annotating a function parameter with a bound `TypeVar`, giving it a default value results in the parameter having a union type between the `TypeVar` and the default value type, *even though* the default value is of the `TypeVar` type.

Example:

```py
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

Instance = TypeVar("Instance", bound=A)

def get_instance(cls: type[Instance] = A) -> Instance:
    return cls()
```

Running mypy yields the following error: `error: Incompatible default for argument "cls" (default has type "Type[A]", argument has type "Type[Instance]")`.

`reveal_type` is correct in both cases:

```py
instance_a = get_instance(cls=A)
reveal_type(instance_a)  # note: Revealed type is "A"

instance_b = get_instance(cls=B)
reveal_type(instance_b)  # note: Revealed type is "B"
```

How do I correctly annotate `get_instance` so that I can keep the default argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [very old `mypy` issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3737).

The general solution is using `overload`'s, it can be applied in your case:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, overload

class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

_Instance = TypeVar("_Instance", bound=A)

@overload
def get_instance() -> A: ...
@overload
def get_instance(cls: type[_Instance]) -> _Instance: ...
def get_instance(cls: type[A] = A) -> A:
    return cls()

instance_a = get_instance(cls=A)
reveal_type(instance_a)  # note: Revealed type is "A"

instance_b = get_instance(cls=B)
reveal_type(instance_b)  # note: Revealed type is "B"
```

For type checking purposes, we define two overloads. Implementation signature is checked only within the function, external callers see only the overloads. Here we just ignore specific relationship between `cls` type and return type while checking body, however, you can consider other solutions from the linked issue.

[Try me in playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&gist=34e227611853d1a99a5bb5dbf77be3a0)

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly. I was missing the "empty" overload to make this work.