# Creating generic type argument bound to Exception in Python

Tags: python, exception, mypy, type-annotation

I'm trying to create a generic type for an exception, to be sent to a method. This is what I have, currently:

```
E = TypeVar("E", bound=Exception)
```

I would annotate the argument like this:

```
def parse_td_value(
        self,
        data: Tag,
        name: str,
        parser: Callable[[str], T],
        exc_type: Type[E] = ValueError,
    ) -> T:
    ...
```

However, when I do this mypy gives me an error:

> Incompatible default for argument "exc_type" (default has type "Type[ValueError]", argument has type "Type[E]")

I have attempted to resolve this issue using overloads, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75058589/annotating-function-with-typevar-and-default-value-results-in-union-type), but to no avail. I'm assuming this has something to do with the fact that the bound condition of `E` is different than the type of the default argument for the method, `ValueError`.

To my mind, this doesn't make sense because `ValueError` should be a `E`. So, why is mypy disagreeing here and how can I make this annotation work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Annotating function with TypeVar and default value results in union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75058589/annotating-function-with-typevar-and-default-value-results-in-union-type)

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike I'm afraid that didn't fix it.

Comment: In the updated code `E` is just a raw type variable, used only once in a signature. While this may be important in rare cases when dealing with container variance, you need just `exc_type: type[Exception] = ValueError` without any type variable involved.

Comment: But just applying the linked answer also works for your case. [Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=4c2731de7b04f06074f413957196a207)

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike Except it didn't, though. I applies the linked answer in my codebase but the mypy error remained.

Comment: It resolves the problem for code you posted. If it does not happen to your full code, please update MRE to reflect this - my comment does answer the question as currently written, and I have no idea what is different in your setup.

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike What version of mypy did you test this with? For reference, I'm using Python 3.10 and mypy 1.0.0.

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike That being said, your suggestion to change the line to be `type[Exception] = ValueError` actually resolved the problem so that seems like a better answer to me than creating overloads.

Comment: Versions are defined in playground linked above. [works](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=1.0.0&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=3ade218551318d81f59d29ca80f4713d) with `mypy==1.0.0` and py3.10 too.