# Python <=3.11 generic factory classmethod

Tags: python, typing

I'd like to convert the `Dict[str, Any]` coming from a POST call into a class like the following:

```py
from typing import Callable, Generic, TypeVar

RecordT = TypeVar("RecordT")

@dataclass
class Message(Generic[RecordT]):
  # Some fields that are always in a Message
  # ... 
  records: List[RecordT]
```

`"records"` is always a string-valued field in the input message, but its semantic type can be different. Sometimes I'll `json.loads` from it and it'll be its own dict I want to parse into an object; sometimes it'll just be a string. When it's all working, I'd like to be able to do the following:

```py
message_with_foos: Message[Foo] = Message.from_dict(
    foo_d,
    lambda s: Foo.from_dict(json.loads(s)))
message_with_bars: Message[Bar] = Message.from_dict(
    bar_d,
    lambda s: Bar.from_dict(json.loads(s)))
# or indeed
message_with_baz_of_qux: Message[Baz[Qux]] = Message.from_dict(
    bq_d,
    lambda s: Baz.from_dict(
        json.loads(s),
        lambda s2: Quz.from_dict(json.loads(s2)))
# but equally importantly,
message: Message[str] = Message.from_dict(d)
```

This last one is important, for simplicity of interface. Devs will be more likely to use this library if there is a straightforward option, and if the power is just a special case.

It seems like I should be able to do the following:

```py
  @classmethod
  def from_dict(cls, d: Dict[str, Any], body_fn: Callable[[str], RecordT] = str) -> "Message[RecordT]":
    # Parse other fields
    # ...
    cls(# other stuff,
        records=[body_fn(r) for r in d["Records"]])
```

MyPy mostly likes this, but it quarrels with the default value for `body_fn` being `str`: `Incompatible default for argument "f" (default has type "Type[str]", argument has type "Callable[[str], RecordT]")`

I feel so close; how do you do this?

Comment: Could you clarify how `body_fn: Callable[[str], RecordT] = str` is supposed to work? `str` returns a `str`, not a `RecordT`. Do you want it to be legal for `body_fn` to return a `str` instead of a `RecordT`? Or do you want to guarantee that `RecordT` is compatible with `str`?

Comment: Thanks for the question! Let me make sure to clarify my intentions. I'd like the Message class to be parametric, and I'm using `RecordT` as the formal name of that parameter. Since this is a class method, if I understand correctly `RecordT` is unbound in the context of the method. If it's provided a `Callable[[str], int]`, `RecordT` gets bound to `int` in the returned `Message`. If it's provided a `Callable[[str], [str]]`, which `str` is, `RecordT` should get bound to str. I should say, I've spent a lot more time in Java than Python, so I may be missing critical things about the type system

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Annotating function with TypeVar and default value results in union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75058589/annotating-function-with-typevar-and-default-value-results-in-union-type)