# Type hinting argument defaults with generics in python

Tags: python, generics, mypy

I have some code which boils down to the following:

```py
from typing import Callable, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

def default_fn() -> str:
    return "Hello world!"

def call_fn(fn: Callable[[], T] = default_fn) -> T:
    return fn()
```

Note I'm on Python 3.10, so I'm unable to try the new 3.12 syntax for generics.

The focus of the question is on the very general `call_fn` function for which I wish to use a generic type hint to show the return type of the argument matches the return type of `call_fn`. I also want a default argument, which here is `default_fn`. To my surprise, Mypy (1.2.0 if that's relevant) complains about this:

```
$ mypy foo.py
foo.py:8: error: Incompatible default for argument "fn" (default has type "Callable[[], str]", argument has type "Callable[[], T]")  [assignment]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

(line 8 is the line `def call_fn...`)

**What's the most "Pythonic" way to fix this error (or to fix this code)?** The fixes I've come across all have some kind of drawback:

1. Replace the return type of `default_fn` to `Any`

This option isn't the worst thing in the world, but as I understand it `Any` should be avoided when you can be more precise, *especially* for return types.

2. Replace both occurences of `T` on line 8 with `T | str`, or whatever the return type of the default function is

This is a little ugly, and is also very confusing to read (why do you need to specify a type when you're already using a generic type?)

3. Not use a default function, instead making the argument `Optional[Callable[[], T]] = None`, and setting the argument to `default_fn` with the function body

This isn't *horrible*, there are other reasons to use this pattern e.g. when you want a default value to be something mutable. Still, it's harder to read than having the default function in the usual place you'd expect to see a default i.e. in the function signature, and this is only a common pattern because it's *necessary* in those situations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Annotating function with TypeVar and default value results in union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75058589/annotating-function-with-typevar-and-default-value-results-in-union-type)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a fourth option.. use `typing.overload`. You can specify that when there are no arguments that you return a str, otherwise its a generic function over the parameters. The actual implementation can be set to return `Any`.

```
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, overload, Any

T = TypeVar("T")


def default_fn() -> str:
    return "Hello world!"


@overload
def call_fn() -> str:
    ...


@overload
def call_fn(fn: Callable[[], T]) -> T:
    ...


def call_fn(fn: Callable[[], Any] = default_fn) -> Any:
    return fn()
```