# How to type hint a method that returns an instance of a class passed as parameter, with default value?

Tags: python, generics, mypy

*using Python 3.11 and Mypy 1.7.*

I am trying to properly type hint a method that takes a class as parameter, with a default value, and returns an instance of that class. The class passed as parameter must be a subclass of a specific base class.
How should I do that?
I tried to use a [type variable with upper bound](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#type-variables-with-upper-bounds) like this:

```
from typing import TypeVar


class BaseClass: pass
class ImplClass(BaseClass): pass

T = TypeVar("T", bound=BaseClass)

def method(return_type: type[T] = ImplClass) -> T:
    return return_type()
```

But mypy complains with this message:

```
scratch_10.py: note: In function "method":
scratch_10.py:9:35: error: Incompatible default for argument "return_type" (default has type "type[ImplClass]", argument has type "type[T]")  [assignment]
    def method(return_type: type[T] = ImplClass) -> T:
                                      ^~~~~~~~~
```

But as far as I understand this error is wrong since the default `ImplClass` is a subclass of `BaseClass` which is the upper bound of `T`, so it respects the type constraints.

Note that removing the upperbound does not help:

```py
T = TypeVar("T") #no upperbound this time
def method(return_type: type[T] = ImplClass) -> T:
    return return_type()
```

(same error message)

But removing the default value and explicitly calling `method` with `ImplClass` as parameter works without any complaints:

```py
def method(return_type: type[T]) -> T: # no default value this time
    return return_type()

method(ImplClass)
```

> Success, no issues found in 1 source file

So I don't understand why `mypy` complains about the default value but not about the actual parameter with the exact same value. Is that a false positive in `mypy`, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Annotating function with TypeVar and default value results in union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75058589/annotating-function-with-typevar-and-default-value-results-in-union-type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known limitation of mypy. See the GitHub issues [#8739 - mypy reporting error with default value for typevar](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8739) and [#3737 - Unable to specify a default value for a generic parameter](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3737) for its discussion.

You can make this work using [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) to separately annotate the case where the default value is used:

```
from typing import TypeVar, overload


class BaseClass: pass
class ImplClass(BaseClass): pass

T = TypeVar("T", bound=BaseClass)


@overload
def method() -> ImplClass:
    ...
     
@overload    
def method(return_type: type[T]) -> T:
    ...

def method(return_type=ImplClass):
    return return_type()
    

reveal_type(method())           # ok: ImplClass
reveal_type(method(BaseClass))  # ok: BaseClass
reveal_type(method(ImplClass))  # ok: ImplClass
# reveal_type(method(int))      # error
```

This passes type checking with mypy (Python 3.12, v1.7.1), and outputs

```
main.py:23: note: Revealed type is "__main__.ImplClass"
main.py:24: note: Revealed type is "__main__.BaseClass"
main.py:25: note: Revealed type is "__main__.ImplClass"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

[Try it yourself online](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=e7a75bf6565f43e64fc77f3bd14f4b4e).

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer. I like to find bugs in 2023 that were reported in 2017 ^^ makes me feel young :D

Comment: With Python 3.11, mypy stills complains with `error: Function is missing a type annotation  [no-untyped-def]` on `def method(return_type=ImplClass):`

Comment: @Guillaume That's due to passing `--strict`. You can either silence that line, or fill in union type hints for the last overload. `def method(return_type: type[T] | type[ImplClass] = ImplClass) -> T | ImplClass:`