# Make Mypy accept a generic dict type with an empty dict default value

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, python-3.11

I'm trying to make Mypy accept a generic param that conforms to a dict. No matter what I do, it is always complaining with:

> Incompatible default for argument "overrides" (default has type "dict[str, Any]", argument has type "T_Overrides") [Mypyassignment]

I know there are some Mypy issues with generics and defaults (this is using 3.11), so maybe there's nothing I can do here?

```
from collections.abc import Hashable
from typing import Any, Never, TypeVar

K = TypeVar("K", bound=Hashable)
V = TypeVar("V")


StrKeyDict = dict[str, Any]
EmptyDict = dict[str, Never]

# Also tried:
#   GenericDict = dict[K, V]
#   StrKeyDict = GenericDict[str, Any]
#   EmptyDict = GenericDict[K, Never]

T = TypeVar("T", bound=StrKeyDict | EmptyDict)

# Also tried:
#   T = TypeVar("T", bound=dict[str, Any])

class ScriptArgs:
    def __init__(self, overrides: T = {}):
#                                     ~~ Mypy complains here
        ...
```

Comment: You usually don't want to use a dict or list as a default value, because all calls to the function will share the same dict. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Yup @Barmar, good callout – when I do, I do `overrides = overrides.copy()` (or `deepcopy` if necessary).

Comment: Annotating an argument with a type variable and then providing a default value doesn't work. Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75058589/annotating-function-with-typevar-and-default-value-results-in-union-type

Comment: Are you sure this is valid? `EmptyDict = dict[str, Never]`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it seems to, but happy to be wrong here 

Comment: @dROOOze gross. That seems to be it, thanks.