# Python mypy typing inference involving unions and lists

Tags: python, mypy, type-hinting

Hi all I'm a bit confused about mypy's behavior involving unions and list.
here is a simplified version to help explain:

```py
from typing import Union


class A:
    pass

class B:
    pass


def f(items, a: Union[type[A], type[B]]) -> Union[list[A], list[B]]:
    return [a() for x in items] # Incompatible return value type (got "list[Union[A, B]]", expected "Union[list[A], list[B]]")
```

I expect the list comprehension to create a homogenous list of either `A` or `B`. Mypy infers that the list is heterogenous and can contain items of both type `A` and `B` at the same time. I don't see why it should since the parameter `a` is either `A` or `B` but does not change during the list creation.

Technically you don't even need the list comprehension (though in our use case we process a list items using one of several classes). The following will also error:

```py
def f(a: Union[type[A], type[B]]) -> Union[list[A], list[B]]:
    return [a()]
```

Is my understanding of the situation incorrect? Is there a better way to write the function to ensure the output signature (I do indeed want one of several homogenous lists from this function).

Comment: You have a line of people (Iterable) that potentially includes both men and women (Union[A, B]). Then you put them in a room (List). You now have a room that contains potentially men and women (List[Union[A, B]]), not a room of only men (List[A]) or only women (List[B]), i.e. `Union[List[A], List[B]]`.

Comment: I'm not sure the first line applies to this situation since the type is fixed at function call time. In my view it would be like you have a collection of people both men and women. Then a fixed person says either "Men go into the room now" (A) or "Women go into the room now" (B). Then I would expect the room to have either only men or only women.

Comment: You're confusing runtime with static analysis: the person who says "men/women go into the room now" doesn't come along until *later*, when you are designating the room (defining the type) you don't know in advance which it will be, because the *type* of the queue is Men|Women, and the function acts on the type of the *queue*. There are plenty of times when you actually *want* `List[Union[A, B]]`, the typechecker can't magically intuit that you meant the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *typechecker* doesn't know which of `A` or `B` is passed, so it cannot determine the type of `a()` more specifically than `A|B`. As a result, the list has type `list[A|B]`, not `list[A] | list[B]`.

You should define a generic function with a constrained type variable instead.

```
from typing import TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T', A, B)


def f(items, t: type[T]) -> list[T]:
    return [t() for x in items]
```

From the perspective of the type checker, you have now defined *two* functions, one of type `Callable[[Any, Type[A]], list[A]]` and one of type `Callable[[Any, Type[B]], list[B]]`, rather than a single function of type `Callable[[Any, Type[A]|Type[B]], list[A]|list[B]]`. The type of argument for `t` will actually determine which of the two will be called and should be type-checked:

```
f(something, A)  # call the Callable[[Any, Type[A]], list[A]] version
f(something, B)  # call the Callable[[Any, Type[B]], list[B]] version
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the way forward. There's another issue with default arguments with generics but that seems to be an [open problem in mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3737) so will probably have to silence that until it's fixed.

Comment: There could be a way around it. The underlying problem is that a generic function is, in some sense, a *family* of functions, here one that *only* takes a subclass of `A` and returns a `list[A]`, and one that only takes a subclass of `B` and returns `list[B]`. Basically, you need a "generic" default, but there's no one way to do that. If you want to briefly mention your probably, I can try addressing it here, but a new question might be better.

Comment: @fhassan-cl for generic argument's default value see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75058589/annotating-function-with-typevar-and-default-value-results-in-union-type/75058916#75058916. The ticket is open to (maybe) provide direct support in future, but a direct, non-magic workaround exists.

Comment: I actually saw that, however imo if I'm putting a workaround anyways it would be more clear to just do a `# type: ignore[assignment]` and explain with a comment next to the code. Thanks for sharing!